# I am just not able to wrap my head around such a simple program.Please help. Below is the program and a representation of my understanding

Tags: c, pointers, swap

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x, y, *a, *b, temp;

   printf("Enter the value of x and y\n");
   scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);

   printf("Before Swapping\nx = %d\ny = %d\n", x, y);

   a = &x;
   b = &y;

   temp = *b;  
   *b = *a;    
   *a = temp;  

   printf("After Swapping\nx = %d\ny = %d\n", x, y);

   return 0;
}
```

[Picture of my understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUkRg.png)

> I understand that a pointer is a variable that holds the address of another
>   variable . But I am simply not able to wrap my head around this.Thanks in 
>   advance for the help .

Comment: You never asked a question

Comment: Sorry , if i was not clear . I need to understand how this program works . I am beginner and my understanding of the program is in the picture . [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUkRg.png) . Thanks

Comment: ah I see you asked your question, in the picture. let's fix your question first.

Comment: @Major maybe make your question explicit in text so people don't have to click on the picture?

Comment: The arrows are backwards in your diagram. The pointers point to the ints, not the other way around

Comment: don't put links up for your questions, because that's just going to get you downvoted. You should make sure that what you're asking is actually presented in the question above, that way 1) it will stay there 2) it will help others search for it, *and* no one likes clicking on links because they could be malicious

Comment: Okay ! will do that . Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well actually this is what is happening. Suppose you enter 1,2.

```
0x100000       0x100007
--------+-------+-------+---// --------+
        |       |       |
    1   |       |  2    |
--------+-------+-------+--// --------+
   x               y


a = &x;  // 0x100000
b = &y;  // 0x100007

----------------+-...+---------------+
                |    |               |
0x100000        |    |0x100007       |
----------------+-...+---------------+
    a                     b


temp = *a; // means go at the address that is contained by me and give me that value
// temp = 1;

*a = *b;  // put the value at address pointed by b to the address pointed by a

*b = temp; // put the value we kept in temp in the address pointed by b.
```

#### How did it swap?

The thing is there are two variables `x` and `y`. Now when you  wanted to fill it out, you passed to `scanf()` the address of `x` and `y`. Why did you pass the address? Because only by accesing those address the `scanf()` will write to the variables. And you can check the change in `main()`.

Now let's see what happens next:

The thing is there are two variables

```
int*x, *y;
```

They are integer pointers. What are they? They can hold address of an `int` variable. Well `int` variable like `a` and `b`. Now that's all good. You want to get the address of `a` and `b` and store them. So you wrote

```
x=&a;
y=&b;
```

With this, you hold the address of `a` and `b`.

Then what?

You have introduced another variable. `temp` which can hold `int` values.

Now you wrote

```
temp = *a;
```

That means, "hey, whatever address you have, fetch me the value that is in that address". `a` has `x`'s address. And `x` contains `1`. `temp` now contains `1`.

```
*a = *b;
```

Same way, now you say, write the value that you get from the address that is contained in `b` and put that value somewhere. That somewhere is nowhere else other than the address contained in `a`. At that address you have the content of `x` variable. So you just made a change to variabnle `x`.

```
*b = temp;
```

Well this is simialar. Now you at the address that is contained in `b` write down the value conatined in  `temp`. The address conatined in `b` is `y`'s address. You made change to `y`'s value.

That's how they swapped.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is flawed.

```
a = &x; makes pointer a point to address of x;
b = &y; makes pointer b point to address of y;

temp = *b;//set variable temp equal to the dereferenced value of b, *b implies the following: dereference b, which in this case means to obtain the value b is pointing to. temp value is y.

*b = *a; // set the value b points to equal to the value a points to.  Now y value equals to x.
*a = temp// dereference a and set the value a points to equal to temp.  Now x is set to y, and y was set to x previously thus x doesn't change.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just `swapping using pointers`.

```
temp = *b;  
// *b is the value of y, here we store the value pointed to by b in temp
*b = *a;    
// *a is the value of x, here we store the value pointed to by a in y,
// here *b is nothing but y as noted in first step
*a = temp;  
// Here you understand the intention of using temp, the old value
// of y is no more, so use temp and we assign its value to *a ie x
```

Answer (score 0):

The picture is somewhat wrong.

Lets say x is at address 0x100h
y at address 0x200h

Initially

> a points to 0x100h

while

> b points to 0x200h

In your code you have swapped the values inside the addresses and not the address pointed by a or b.

But the picture that you have used to visualize says that you have actually swapped the address pointed by a and b which is wrong. Try this code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x, y, *a, *b, temp;

   printf("Enter the value of x and y\n");
   scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);

   printf("Before Swapping\nx = %d\ny = %d\n", x, y);
   printf("Address of x= %p and address of y= %p\n",(void*)&x,(void*)&y);
   a = &x;
   b = &y;
   printf("a holds the address: %p \nb holds the address %p\n",a,b);

   temp = *b;
   *b = *a;
   *a = temp;

   printf("After Swapping\nx = %d\ny = %d\n", x, y);
   printf("Address of x= %p and address of y= %p\n",(void*)&x,(void*)&y);
   printf("a holds the address: %p \nb holds the address %p\n",a,b);
   return 0;
}
```